# Pandas specify line format

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use `pandas` to read [earthquake catalogues](http://service.scedc.caltech.edu/ftp/catalogs/SCSN/) provided by SCEDC. Probably for historical reasons, the file format is rather obscure, as detailed in the `README`:

```
col len format name comment
--- --- ------ ---- -------
 1   4    a4   year YYYY
 6   2    a2   mon  MM
 9   2    a2   day  DD
13   2    a2   hour HH  (UTC time:
16   2    a2   min  mm   7 hours ahead of Pacific Daylight Time
19   5   f5.2  sec  SS.ss    8 hours ahead of Pacific Standard Time)
    25   3    i3   lat  degrees 
    29   5   f5.2  lat      minutes 
    34   4    i4   lon  degrees  
    39   5   f5.2  lon  minutes
45   1    a1   quality  location quality
                'A'  +- 1 km horizontal distance
                     +- 2 km depth
                'B'  +- 2 km horizontal distance
                     +- 5 km depth
                'C'  +- 5 km horizontal distance
                     no depth restriction
                'D'  >+- 5 km horizontal distance
                'Z'  no quality listed in database
47   3   f3.1  magnitude
54   6   f6.2  depth    kilometers
60   3    i3   nph  number of picked phases
67   5   f5.2  rms  root mean square of travel times
73   8    i8   eventid  event ID
```

which amounts to this:

```
#YYY MM DD  HH mm SS.ss  LATITUDE LONGITUDE Q MAG     DEPTH NPH    RMS   EVID
2008 01 01  02 37 08.85  33 35.95-116 43.56 A 0.7     13.16 41     0.16 10297549
2008 01 01  05 12 06.46  33 37.12-116 39.90 A 0.8     13.03 48     0.23 10297553
2008 01 02  18 31 42.73  34 50.89-118 45.92 C 1.1     -1.28 11     0.28 10297805
```

While I don't mind the space-delimited format, things are getting nasty in the `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` columns: each coordinate component is given in `[degrees] [minutes]` format (e.g. `33 35.95` and `-116 43.56` for the first earthquake), but there is no space between the latitude minutes and longitude degrees (`33 35.95-116 43.56`), which makes it hard to split the line properly.

Is there a way to provide that obscure (`a4 a2 f5.2 i3` etc.) format to `pandas.read_csv` to specify how to split and interpret each line in the catalogue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read your csv as normal and split the problematic column:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s+', header=None)
```

which gives:

```
    0       1   2   3   4   5       6   7           8       9   10  11      12  13      14
0   2008    1   1   2   37  8.85    33  35.95-116   43.56   A   0.7 13.16   41  0.16    10297549
1   2008    1   1   5   12  6.46    33  37.12-116   39.90   A   0.8 13.03   48  0.23    10297553
2   2008    1   2   18  31  42.73   34  50.89-118   45.92   C   1.1 -1.28   11  0.28    10297805
```

As we can see, the `7` column contains `-`, so we can do:

```
df[['a','b']] = df[7].str.split('-',expand=True)
```

and rename properly.

Comment: Neat trick, there's just one problem: other columns may contain negative values. For instance, the `DEPTH` may occasionally be negative (which is wrong, but still, it's there). This messes up your solution. I've added such a case to my question

Comment: Basically what you pass to `sep` is some regex patterns. I tried some but they didn't work as expected. So I updated with a work-around.